# Django Rest Framework using generic Class Based View is not render "Create Form" when Permission IsAuthenticated set

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-framework

I pretty new I Django ReST Framework,
I have created `Token Authentication` on my `settings.py`
My `views.py` was configured using `generic Class Based View`.
I found that when no authentication configured on `settings.py`, the List `Class Based View` will render `JSON List` and `Create Form` properly.
But after I configured the `Authentication`, it only shows the list, but no `Create Form`
It is same on `Detail View` and `Update`

Most of authentication tutorial will bring to `Function Based View` using `View Decorator`

My Settings:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {

'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
    'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication'
],

'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
    'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly'
]
```

}

My Views.py:

```
class ProductListView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have applied 'IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly' permission class, instead of that you have to apply 'IsAuthenticated' permission class

Comment: i have use IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly now.

Comment: i just realize, that even i cannot create an account via API after the authentication is applied

Comment: after i use IsAuthenticated, i found that all my accounts have no credentials. But why my account app does the same, even i did not configure the permissions. Or should i create a AllowAny to Account permission?